# How To have dynamic container size

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose I have a Container of width 400 ( blue containers ).

this container has a fixex padding from left:20 and from right:12

but my problem is that how can I shrink blue container if user input is short ( red text )

means the blue container should have that fixed padding but the width can change according to red text .

fucus that if I have multiLine text , I have no any problem.

the way I put blue container is that in scaffold row I have fixed size avatar and fixed size 70 pixels at the end of row and wrap the blue container in Expanded

```
Row (
children:[
SizedBox(width:100),
Expanded(child:BlueContainer()),
SizedBox(width:70),
]
)
```

[image: chat app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code for you, i get the constraints from layoutbuilder;

```
Container(
   constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth * 0.65, minWidth: 
   constraints.maxWidth * 0.1),
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
     color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
   ),
   child: Text('${f.text}'),
  ),
),
```